# Unable to run single spec files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

Today, i've encountered a really strange issue with my specs. When i runs a spec command without specifying any specific dir/file, my tests are working great, all green. However, if i'll specify a dir or file, rspec throws few (randomish) errors depending on if i'm using rspec with spring or not. What's more - yesterday, just before my work end, everything was working well. I have not touched anything since then and now it's broken for some reason. Here is how it goes:

- `rspec spec/requests/api/v1/users_spec.rb`
  results in
  `uninitialized constant FactoryGirl`
- `spring stop; spring rspec spec/requests/api/v1/users_spec.rb`
  results in
  `undefined local variable or method 'some_url_helper_here'`

While running `spring rspec` or `rspec` works well without any exceptions. My spec file looks more or less like that:

```
# spec/requests/api/v1/users_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Users API v1', :type => :request do
  before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) # that line throws an exception about unitialized constant FactoryGirl
  end

  # ...
end
```

Have you any idea what the hell is going on in here? Thanks in advance for any clues.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with dependencies not properly satisfied in your project's `require`s.

As a whole, everything is loaded when you run or test the whole application. But some individual project files, loaded by individual specs, do not process the correct `require`s, or process them in the wrong order (too late to reference the symbol).

You will need to work through your files, running specs individually, locate the missing symbol and ensure the relevant library is `require`d before it is used. Once you have figured out the correct dependencies this way, you may want to factor out common ones into a single helper. You may want to arrange them to meet a consistent style/convention too, e.g. singular dependencies get `require`d only in the file that needs them, otherwise have two helpers - one for loading test/development dependencies, itself `require`d in all separate test helpers and scripts, and one for loading application runtime dependencies.

Also, check your project for "clever" autoloading of everything in a folder, e.g.

```
Dir["lib/*.rb"].each{ |file| require file  }
```

That can randomise the load order due to your file system. If there are actually dependencies between those files so that 'x.rb' must load before 'y.rb', then you will get systematic success/fail depending on what happened to your machine the last time that folder's contents changed.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But what about the fact that it was working yesterday? And it happened to me few times before. It's allways the same - i'm working on my project, stops for a while and when i'm back, it act's like that again. Then, after some time away, everything is back to normal. It's insane

Comment: @mbajur: Do you have any code that is auto-loading required files, using a directory listing, e.g. `Dir["lib/*.rb"].each{|file| require file }`? That can randomise the load order due to your file system, meaning you will get systematic success/fail depending on what happened the last time that folder's contents changed.

Comment: Well, i have nothing like that written by myself, just the default ones made by raiils/rspec generators.